# Should I erase previous Linux on a bootable live usb first when I want to create a different one?

Tags: dual-boot, usb-drive, live-usb, flash-memory

I have an UEFI laptop. I've created a bootable live usb flash with a Linux and then decided I wanted to install another distributive of Linux. How can I properly create a bootable usb again: should I dd with /dev/zero first? Or can I repeat the initial procedure of creating bootable usb for the new Linux?

Comment: How are you creating your bootable USB device?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no need at-all to blank your USB device.
Just use

```
dd
```

command, and it will overwrite everything (it needs) to be a boot-able USB linux distro

Comment: though this answer may may seem to suffice to you, it does not to me, running `dd` without proper arguments is not-an-answer to me

Comment: Complete your answer, this is perplexing.

Comment: @burian.vlastimil, что ты пристал к человеку? напиши свой тогда.

Comment: @Johshi No mate, he's not, ebal's answer was right, but so perplexing!

Comment: `dd` on its own, with no arguments, just copies STDIN to STDOUT and doesn't touch USB devices at all.  This answer appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever procedure you use to create a bootable USB has to overwrite what was already there. It doesn't matter that what was already there was a bootable system as opposed to a straight-from-the-factory blank or some random data. Erasing stuff only to overwrite it immediately afterwards is pointless. Just repeat the initial procedure.

Zeroing the drive would only make sense if you had confidential data on it and you wanted to make sure that it can't be recovered. Creating a bootable USB drive might not overwrite the whole drive, only the bits that are used on the drive — typically the bootable system is smaller than the drive and so some data would remain at the end of the drive. If your objective is just to get a working USB drive, you don't need to do anything other than the bootable USB drive creation procedure.

Comment: so it won't overwrite everything and will possibly just a part of it. what if a part that's not been overwritten and remained untouched will somehow mess up the installation process of a new OS or interferer with it?

Comment: @Johshi No, it can't affect the installation process. The installation process overwrites all the parts that need to be overwritten. The second time works just like the first time. There's nothing magical about having had a bootable system before that's different from not having had a bootable system before.

Answer (score 0):

Format the USB first e,g:

```
mkfs.vfat -F32 -I /dev/sdb
```

Then create your bootable USB using the command `dd` e,g:

```
dd if=path/to/your.iso of=/dev/sdb && sync
```

The official website of [**Arch-linux**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media) recommand repartionning and refoarmating the usb drive after using the command `dd`

> **Warning**: This will irrevocably destroy all data on /`dev/sdx`. To restore the USB drive as an empty, usable storage device after using the Arch ISO image, the iso9660 filesystem signature needs to be removed by running `wipefs --all /dev/sdx` as root, before r**epartitioning** and **reformating** the USB drive.

Comment: If you are going to `dd` the image over the top of `/dev/sdb` then you don't need to `mkfs.vfat` it first; the `dd` will just blow away the filesystem just created.